# Access class object by its parameters?

Tags: python, list, class, search

Is there any way to find an object saved in a list, knowing only its parameters and without traversing the said list?

For example, there's a class, objects of which have an (x;y) coordinate, and none of the objects share the same coordinate (all x/y pairs are distinct and **do not** repeat). These objects are all saved in a list:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

points = [Point(...), Point(...), Point(...), Point(...), ...]
```

Whenever I need the specific instance, is there any way to find it (here: its index in the list) by using just its coordinates without traversing the whole list like here:

```
def find_objects_index(x, y):
    for i in range(len(points)):
        if points[i].x == x and points[i].y == y:
            return i
```

EDIT: these `Point()`s are to be accessed for writing, not reading, and so `object.x` and `object.y` **will** be changing, you can't just create a dictionary with `(object.x, object.y)` as keys - you'd need to add a new entry and delete the old one each time.

Comment: I like dicts, so, if you define it as a dict with they key being a tuple(x,y) you can instantly get that point...... BUT in your use case, creating a class called Point wouldnt have metadata that would be beneficial unless you were just checking for the existence of that point.  You might not want the overhead of this implementation though as it is taking up a bunch of space.

Comment: "you'd need to add a new entry and delete the old one each time" - then do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to find an object saved in a list, knowing only its
>   parameters and without traversing the said list?

Short answer: No.

If you want or need to traverse such a collection of data points rapidly, perhaps you should consider using an type other than a list--a binary tree based off x or y data, for example (or if you need to track them separately, perhaps one tree for each)?

Comment: The reason everyone keeps suggesting a dict (dictionary) type for dealing with this is because usually works really well, and you didn't describe anything that would contradict this yet.

See @quamrana 's answer. For the limited information you provided, it's a really good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list aggregation with a condition to get the item(s) you are looking for:

```
matching = [p for p in points if p.x = VALX and p.y == VALX]
```

However, in this case having a dictionary with (x, y) as key is most likely the correct (and well performing) way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `Points` in a `dict()`:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

points_list = [Point(...), Point(...), Point(...), Point(...), ...]
points_dict = {(p.x,p.y):p for p in points_list}


def find_object(x, y):
    if (x,y) in points_dict:
        return points_dict[(x,y)]

def replace_object(x, y, new_point):
    points_dict.pop((x, y), None)
    points_dict[(new_point.x, new_point.y)] = new_point
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Much more concise than the one I cooked up.

Comment: You could replace `find_object` with just `points_dict.get((x,y))` , though.